# Trying to play music from local files for a discord.py bot, doesnt work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The below is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
vcc = ctx.author.channel
channel = None
if vcc != None:
   channel = vcc.name                                                  
   vc = await vcc.connect()  
   vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source = './tally/10 Two Wuv.flac'))
   while vc.is_playing:
        asyncio.sleep(1)
   await vc.disconnect()
else:                                                                           
   await ctx.send("Join a channel first.")                                
return
```

i don't get any errors, just no output, any help would be appreciated! thanks

Comment: This might be you putting it into Stack, but your indentation is way off. Try indenting everything after `async def test(ctx):` once.

Comment: just did that, no output still, also the indentation might look worse worse here because i had to re do it when i posted it here